# Eclipse don't resolve anymore android packages

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm starting to learn android development through that eclipse plug-in. First it was working so so, but now I just made a new project and eclipse can't even find some libraries sometimes, sometimes gives that error "R cannot be resolved into variable". Dunno if it's useful info but this happened right after I opened NetBeans for a test, and I never use netbeans. 
I installed android sdk + eclipse through this tutorial btw:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/318246/complete-installation-guide-for-android-sdk-adt-bundle-on-ubuntu

Screenshot of the error
https://i.stack.imgur.com/bckCe.png

Comment: "R cannot be resolved into variable" has lots of different causes and almost all of them are covered in past discussions here on stack overflow. If you are just starting out on android dev, that means you probably aren't addicted to eclipse yet so switch to Android Studio and avoid future migration pains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"R cannot be resolved into variable" dosn't build

you can also make a rebuild of your project

cause this message has lot of solution not only one if you can make a screen short for you problem be nice